# In a Unicode string, how are planes indicated (or are they not)?

Tags: unicode, plane

I have read the article by Joel and have done a lot of searching. Every site and article on Unicode talks about how there are 16 bits per code point, but Unicode supports more than 2^16 code points with Unicode planes.

But none explain how a Unicode string indicates the plane. Further more, this leaves the question of how a Unicode string can hold characters from multiple planes.

So, how are planes indicated in Unicode strings?

Comment: Unicode does not have 16 bits per code point.  It is 21 bits per code point.

Comment: "Every site and article on Unicode talks about how there are 16 bits per code point"—then every site and article is wrong. Unicode code points are integers from 0 to approx. one million and cannot be stored in 16-bit words.

Answer (score 2):

Someone can feel free to correct me on this, I'm still learning about Unicode myself.

I think your confusion is between a code point and how an encoding represents that code point. The number of bits/bytes per code point is going to depend on your encoding. Let's take the simplest example of UTF-32.  UTF-32 uses, drum roll, please  - 32 bits for each code point. It can directly *represent* every Unicode character in each plane.   UTF-16 is a variable length encoding.  It encodes each **code-point** in one or two **code-units**.  The first plane is represented using a single code-unit.  The rest, well, you can read more about it here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8.

In essence, if the encoding supports specific planes, they are there and represented in the encoding.  It's just more clear in the case of UTF-32 than the others.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a chapter that explains this topic (and some other Unicode issues) in a manual for an open-source project. Here is a link to the [PDF manual](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-maintenance-guide.pdf) (read Chapter 10). And here is a link to that chapter in the [HTML version](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-maintenance-guide/internationalisation.html) of the manual.